# Calculate end date from start date and number of days in jquery datepicker when i submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am using  jquery datepicker when i enter days and start date i need to calculate automatically calculate display end date

This is my form submit function

```
$("#promocode").on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault(e);
    var valid_days = $(this).find("[name='valid_days']").val();
    var start_date= $(this).find("[name='start_date']").val();
    var end_date = new Date($(this).val());
    end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() + valid_days);
    var end= $('#end_date').val( (end_date.getMonth() + 1)+ '/' + end_date.getDate() + '/' + end_date.getFullYear() );
    console.log(end);
});
```

When i enter days and start date it display end date like this  `NaN/NaN/NaN` in my end date field

So what is the problem is there any other way to get my end date using jquery datepicker

Comment: need to give start date values here like this  var end_date = new Date(start_date);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse Valid days by using `parseInt` like

```
// for number use ParseInt
var valid_days = parseInt($(this).find("[name='valid_days']").val());
```

And pass `start_date` to calculate valid_days in it like,

```
var valid_days = parseInt($(this).find("[name='valid_days']").val());
var start_date= $(this).find("[name='start_date']").val();
var end_date = new Date(start_date); // pass start date here
end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() + valid_days);
var end= $('#end_date').val( (end_date.getMonth() + 1)+ '/' + end_date.getDate() + '/' + end_date.getFullYear() );
console.log(end);
```

Comment: It working fine now  but the end date date should be in this format yyyy-dd-mm  what should i do now

Comment: just change the sequence as shown here `var end= $('#end_date').val(  end_date.getFullYear() + '-' +end_date.getDate() + '-' +(end_date.getMonth() + 1) );
`

Comment: I changed this ....but for month i select 4 means it display `2017-4-26` but i need `2017-04-26`

Comment: @Karthiga Try `var end= $('#end_date').val(end_date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (end_date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+ '-' + end_date.getDate() );` You can do same for date, also.

Comment: may i know why this plus one here ? end_date.getMonth()+1

Comment: Because `The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).` Read [getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Comment: when i select start date and enter valid days it automatically display end date in date field how i achieve this ...Which jquery function i want to use?

Comment: Use evetns, `change` on start date element and `keyup` on valid days element.

Comment: yyyy-dd-mm is an incredibly confusing format, please use yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change this and try?

```
end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() + parseInt(valid_days));
```

Comment: NO the same NaN

Answer (score 0):

This Could help you. I'm not giving away the whole code as you seem to know what you are doing

```
function plusToDate(currentDate, unit, howMuch) {

var config = {
    second: 1000, // 1000 miliseconds
    minute: 60000,
    hour: 3600000,
    day: 86400000,
    week: 604800000,
    month: 2592000000, // Assuming 30 days in a month
    year: 31536000000 // Assuming 365 days in year
};

var now = new Date(currentDate);

return new Date(now + config[unit] * howMuch);
```

}

This is how you use it

```
var today = new Date();
var theDayAfterTommorow = plusToDate(today, 'day', 2);
```